# question about regex

Tags: c#, regex

i'v got code

```
s = Regex.Match(item.Value, @"\/>.*?\*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;
```

it returns string like '/>test*>', i can replace symbols '/>' and '*>', but how can i return string without this symbols , only string 'test' between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save parts of the regex by putting `()`'s around the area. so for your example:

```
// item.Value ==  "/>test*>"
Match m = Regex.Match(item.Value, @"\/>(.*?)\*>");
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value); // prints the entire match, "/>test*>"
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value); // prints the first saved group, "test*"
```

I also removed `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` because we aren't dealing with any letters specifically, whats an uppercase `/>` look like? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can group patterns inside the regx and get those from the match

```
var    match= Regex.Match(item.Value, @"\/>(?<groupName>.*)?\*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 var data= match.Groups["groupName"].Value
```

Comment: you forgot to place ? before groupname. it should be ?<groupName> and not <groupName>

Comment: also `match` is undefined here

Comment: sorry about mistakes :) i was bit hurry. Thanks

Comment: no problem, but why not go back and edit your mistakes away? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [look-ahead and look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). For your example it would be:

```
var value = Regex.Match(@"(?<=\/>).*?(?=\*>)").Value;
```